# Flutter how to take a photo with custom width and height

Tags: flutter, camera

Is it possible to use flutter camera plugin to take a custom width x height photo? If this is impossible, is there any cropping plugin I can use as a combination to achieve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) plugin if the crop will be handled by user

or

you can display an image and with needed with and height after that you can take the screenshot of [it from the code, see this article for details.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb)

```dart
  Future<Uint8List> _capturePng() async {
    try {
      print('inside');
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
          _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      var bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
      print(pngBytes);
      print(bs64);
      setState(() {});
      return pngBytes;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```